# How to fix Required Iterable but found List in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mutablelist

Hello iam learning build apps with kotlin but i got stack with this error says "Required Iterable, Found List", how i can solve this problem? please see my code below thanks

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),ProductView {

private lateinit var productAdapter: ProductAdapter
private var productList: MutableList<ProductData> = mutableListOf()
private lateinit var dataPresenter : DataPresenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    initRecycler();
    getProduct()
}

private fun getProduct() {
    dataPresenter = DataPresenter(applicationContext,this)
    dataPresenter.getProduct()
}

private fun initRecycler() {
    productAdapter = ProductAdapter(this,productList)
    rvMain.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
    rvMain.adapter = productAdapter
}

override fun showLoading() {
    pgMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

override fun hideLoading() {
    pgMain.visibility = View.GONE
}

override fun showProduct(products: List<ProductData>?) {
    if (products?.size != 0){
        this.productList.clear()
        this.productList.addAll(products)  // <= Required Iterable<ProductData>, Found List<ProductData>
        productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am not too verse in kotlin but I would not be surprise that it has some method with the name of `iterator` or similar to that. `Iterable` is an interface which means that whatever you are passing, must implement such interface in order to be accepted.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that the error message actually is:

```
Required Iterable<ProductData>, Found List<ProductData>?
```

The question mark at the end is not just punctuation. That is the nullable indicator in Kotlin. A `List<ProductData>` cannot be `null`, but a `List<ProductData>?` can. And I believe that `addAll()` requires a non-`null` value.

Ideally, you should change `ProductView` so that the signature for `showProduct()` is `fun showProduct(products: List<ProductData>)`.

Alternatively, you could rewrite `showProduct()` to be:

```
override fun showProduct(products: List<ProductData>?) {
    if (products?.size != 0){
        this.productList.clear()
        products?.let { this.productList.addAll(it) }
        productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```